# JQuery Modal Login conflict?

Tags: jquery, authentication, popup

I am pulling my hair our, as I can not seem to find any reason why the modal login on this page will not open.

If anyone can see a script conflict please help, as I don't really want to start this page from scratch.

Here is the relevant code.

```
    <span><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Clients Login</a></span> 
                        <span><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Employee Login</a></span>

     <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>           
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/retina.js"></script>     
    <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/to-top.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mosaic.1.0.1.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"></script>              
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.0-packed.js"></script>     
    <script src="js/jquery.meanmenu.js"></script>     
    <script src="js/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>     
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/twitter.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //$.noConflict();
    </script>     
    <script src="js/vendor/response.0.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataString = 'username='+ username + '&password='+ password;

        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "client-login.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            // should have redirected already
            window.location.href = "http://centuryholdingsltd.com/user.php?" + result;
        },
        error: function(result){
          $('#returnmessage').html('<p style="color: red !important; font-family: arial; margin-top: -20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">Please check your login details</p>');
        }
    });

    return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you are triggerring the # login-modal ??

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the modal dialog etc

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I forgot to include this bit:

```
<span><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Clients Login</a></span> 
                    <span><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Employee Login</a></span> 
                </div>                     
            </div>                 
        </div>   
        <div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"> 
        <div class="modal-dialog"> 
            <div class="loginmodal-container"> 
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>                     
                <h1>Login to Your Account</h1> 
                <br> 
                <div id="returnmessage"></div>                     
                <form id="form"> 
                    <input type="text" name="user" id="username" placeholder="Username"> 
                    <input type="password" name="pass" id="password" placeholder="Password"> 
                    <input type="submit" name="login" id="submit" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login"> 
                </form>                     
                <div class="login-help"> 
                    <!-- <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>  -->                         
                </div>                     
                <div class="modal-footer"> 
                    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->                         
                </div>
```